# ListBox not highlighting selection on tab change

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, selection, tabcontrol

I'm currently trying out C# and WPF for the first time.

I have a window with two tabs, `tabA` and `tabB`. Each tab has a list box (they are almost identical), `tabA` has `listboxA` and `tabB` has `listboxB`. When an item in a list box is selected, some information about the item is shown, so that I know that it is selected.

On a certain event `E`, I want an item in `listboxA` or `listboxB` to be highlighted and selected, which one is determined by the logic in my application.

Scenario A is that I am currently on `tabA`. When `E` occurs, an item in `listboxA` is chosen. I call `listboxA.Focus()`, and then `listboxA.SelectedItem = item`. This works fine. `item` is selected, so the information about the item is shown, and the item is highlighted in the list.

Scenario B, where I have my problem, is that I am currently on `tabA`. When `E` occurs, an item in `listboxB` is chosen. I call `tabControl.SelectedItem = tabB` to switch the tab, which works fine. As in Scenario A, I call `listboxB.Focus()` and then `listboxB.SelectedItem = item`. The item is selected, because the information about the item is shown, but, here's the thing: **The item is not highlighted in the list box**.

This also happens when changing from `tabB` to `tabA`. It always happens when I change the tab, but if I stay in the same tab the highlight works fine.

Does anyone know if there's anything else I need to do to give the list box the focus after changing the tab, apart from calling `Focus()`?

Comment: What kind of event `E`?

Comment: E is not an event generated by WPF. The event E is that I double click the item in another list box C, that I did not put in this description since it is a user interaction that is E.

Comment: What happens if you use `listBoxA.SelectedIndex = 2` or `listBoxB.SelectedIndex = 2` instead of setting focus and using `SelectedItem`?

Comment: The behaviour is the same.

Comment: Maybe this is the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928795/cant-select-items-in-listbox-when-using-tabcontrol-wpf

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think so, as I'm able to select the item, it's just not highlighted. If I afterwards select the item manually by clicking it, it works as normal again and is highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

WPF has focus scopes, the list box may be focused inside its scope but the scope itself if may not be focused. Alternatively the list box could have focus but it contains a separate scope for its items which would need to be focused.

Comment: You mean like tabB.Focus()? I tried adding that after tabControl.SelectedItem = tabB, but before listboxB.Focus(), but unfortunately, that didn't change anything.

Comment: @HelenaStaberg: No, the content of the tab, i am not sure if you can get a reference to the needed control though as it may be inside the control template.

Comment: I now fetched the contents with tabB.Content, which was a Grid. I then called Focus() on the retrieved Grid, but that didn't change any behaviour.

Comment: @HelenaStaberg: You need to give keyboard focus to the scope [it seems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx#Logical_Focus), not sure if `Focus` did it (returns a bool indicating that)

Comment: That seems to be relevant indeed, because listbox.Focus() returns True if I stay in the same tab, but False if I change tab. I will experiment with it for a while and see if I can fix it.

Comment: I now went FocusManager.SetIsFocusScope(tabA, true); on both tabs in the constructor of my MainWindow. I also put FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(tabA, listboxA); when I wanted the focus. It works fine, IF i visit the tab and select a random item in the list manually first. It doesn't work before I do that. I wonder what clicking the list box activates...

Comment: @HelenaStaberg: Probably sets keyboard focus to an item within the listbox, the items host may be a scope.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36609/discussion-between-helena-staberg-and-h-b)