# How can I get an event to be raised every time any control is changed?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a long form with a bunch of CheckBox's and occasionally some TextBox inputs. I want an event to be raised any time any control is changed (i.e., any CheckBox state is changed or any TextBox.Text is altered). Is there a global way to do this without having to add an event handler to each and every control?

Comment: may i know why do you want a global event for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the advantages of WPF and its declarative nature is that events are inherited down the visual tree.

```
<Window x:Class="MyApplication.MainWindow"
    ....
   TextBox.TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" CheckBox.Checked="CheckBox_Checked">
```

All `TextBox` and `CheckBox` controls will inherit these event handlers. The same approach can be taken in other controls such as `Grid` so only the controls within the Grid are affected.

Comment: `TextBox_OnLostFocus` is a strange name for a `TextChanged` handler :)

Comment: @hvd - Haha sorry, I was still thinking of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550588/listbox-not-highlighting-selection-on-tab-change#comment27288472_18550588) about focus. Using the same test project.

Comment: Did not know that about WPF, was about to point out that all of the controls could subscribe to the same method (given the signatures both textchanged and checkledchange can be the same), but this shows that and not just says it.

Answer (score 1):

One way do this would be to subclass the `CheckBox` and `TextBox` classes and implement the required handlers in those classes.

You will still need to go through your application and replace the standard `CheckBox` and `TextBox` with your classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TextBoxBase.TextChanged="MainWindow_OnTextChanged" on window or user control.

Answer (score 1):

There are so called class events in WPF. Put this in the form's constructor:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TextBox), TextBox.TextChangedEvent, 
    new RoutedEventHandler(AnyTextBox_OnTextChanged));
```

This way you register a handler to `TextChanged` event of all text boxes. Similarly with check boxes:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(CheckBox), CheckBox.CheckedEvent,
    new RoutedEventHandler(AnyCheckBox_OnChecked));
```